# Integrate Wordpress recent posts into existing website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, blogs

I already have a static website and I want to integrate wordpress site (blog) into existing one. Just to point out that I am Wordpress rookie, so I'm still finding my way to understand the way wordpress works.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

I want to show recent posts on my index.php page, while wordpress site is sitting in sub directory.

I've followed this guide:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

And added following code to the start of index.php

```
<?php
// Include Wordpress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wordpress/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Now in body section of my index.php i want to show recent posts from wordpress site, so I added following:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Now I managed to output raw text to my index.php, without any styling beeing applied to it and images are missing from my posts, even though i linked properly style.css file from wordpress default theme.

How to get default wordpress theme styling to be applied to those recent posts? and of course to get those images from posts to show up as well?

I also watched this tutorial where he managed to achieve my goal, but it's not explained exactly how.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUWu3J359AY&t=559s

Also not sure, since it is old video, maybe something changed in newer versions of Wordpress.

I've lost so much time on this and I'm hoping that someone could help me out, or at least to point me out to the right direction.

I apologize in advance if this is duplicate post, however I was unable to find one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just use some AJAX to fetch the most recent posts via the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) and save yourself from the trouble of learning which PHP files to include from WordPress core to get things working (which, in the future, might become a nightmare in terms of maintenance).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out to me. I'm currently on it and it seems as much easier solution. Can you advise, are there any downsides to this method in terms of SEO?

Comment: If your site loads fast enough, Google won't have any trouble reading your AJAX-loaded content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ajax call to do this or the short way, use the iframe and style a little. things will be ready to use immediately.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out to me. I'm currently on it and it seems as much easier solution. Can you advise, are there any downsides to this method in terms of SEO?

Comment: Well, it depends on that which page you are integrating into iframe, if it's your same website page then, we can control it and it will not affect SEO, but if it's a 3rd party web url, then it will surely affect and you can't control it. Let me know if you have any issue. I am available to help you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pulling from Wordpress to my index.php via AJAX call (get method), still haven't completed everything but hopefully everything will work fine

Comment: I hope you will finish it  soon. for any help, you can mail me.